# Stop a Runnable

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable

In my previous question [Make button method if button clicked or not cliked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388308/make-button-method-if-button-clicked-or-not-cliked), i found my answer like this :

```
Handler visibilityToggler;
Runnable visivilityRunnable;


  visibilityToggler = new Handler();

        visivilityRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                 // isUserClickedButton is used to keep record if user has pressed button within 1 sec
                //  keep isUserClickedButton = true for first time as it will run 
                if (!isUserClickedButton) {

                    // user not pressed button
                    Toast.makeText(context,"You are not pressed the Button",Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
                }

                // toggle visibility
                Random generator = new Random();
                number = generator.nextInt(16);

                for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                    if (i == number)
                        buttons[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    else
                        buttons[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

            // again start the visibility 
              visibilityToggler.postDelayed(visivilityRunnable,1000);

                // make it false as visibility is toggled and we want to track button pressed from start
                isUserClickedButton = false;


            }
        };

visibilityToggler.postDelayed(visivilityRunnable,1000);
```

Now my question is: How to stop a Runnable?
Can anyone can give a code sample?

UPDATE :

i had use the removecallbacks() on a button

```
          public void onClick(View v){
             visibilityToggler.removeCallbacks(visivilityRunnable);
             }
```

but the runnable not stop, anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if do you want to break the loop , but if i understand you i would suggest you to make a static boolean variable and stop it whenever you want

```
public static boolean isWorking=true;
  for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                if(isWork){
                if (i == number)
                    buttons[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    buttons[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else break;}
```

now if you want to break the loop just change `isWork` to false

Answer (score 0):

Define the runnable outside the handler. Then call `handler.removeCallbacks(visivilityRunnable);` where you want to stop the handler.